# Set value of input field based on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

I´m creating a booking form for a group of hotels. Each hotel has a special offer page, which can be accessed by adding the parameter `&ratePlanID=xxx` to the request URL.

How can I add the ratePLanID dynamically when a user selects the hotel from a dropdown list?

I´ve tried to write a function that sets the value of an input field with the correct ratePlanID when a user selects the hotel, but I can´t get it to work.

This is what I came up with: http://jsbin.com/oduhet/3/edit#javascript,html,live

Any ideas what I did wrong here or another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `case` statement you should be looking for string values (vals are Strings not Ints).

Like:

```
switch(hotel)
    {
      case '15205': 
        $('[name=ratePlanID]').val(1);
        break;
      case '15206': 
        $('[name=ratePlanID]').val(2);
        break;
          case '15207': 
        $('[name=ratePlanID]').val(3);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#destination').change(function() {
    var hotel = $('#destination').val();
   $('[name=ratePlanID]').val(hotel);
  });
});
```

replace this in you javascript code

And for switch case

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#destination').change(function() {
    var hotel = $('#destination').val();
   switch(hotel)
{
  case '15205': 
    $('[name=ratePlanID]').val('1');
    break;
  case '15206': 
    $('[name=ratePlanID]').val('2');
    break;
      case '15207': 
    $('[name=ratePlanID]').val('3');
    break;
}

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "case" statement needs to look for "strings" not "ints". Put '' around each case.

Answer (score 0):

A few things. I'm using a much newer version of JQuery since I'm not sure what v1.0 is missing.

I add a listener to the select list using jQuery AFTER the DOM Is ready to be manipulated. This is done by adding a listener to the 'document' waiting for the 'ready' event which, when fired, will execute the function passed to the listener. I've also given the input field the id `ratePlanInput` so that I can refer to it in the JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {    // add listener for document ready
    $('#destination').change(function() {     //add a listener for change
      var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
      $('#ratePlanInput').val(selectedValue);
    });

  });


</script>

</head><body>


<form action="http://www.example.com" method="get">

  <select name="hotelID" id="destination">
    <option value="" class="first_option" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a property:</option> 
    <option value="15205">City Hotel</option> 
    <option value="15206">Beach Hotel</option>
    <option value="15207">Business Hotel</option> 
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="ratePlanID" value="" id="ratePlanInput" />           

  <button type="submit">Check availability</button>     

</form>  


</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I needed to pass another value to the input field, not the value of the selected option. That´s why I used the switch statement. The "1" in the jQuery request link (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js) is a bit confusing: it doesn´t load v1.0 but the latest version from Google libs. Have a look at the source code: it´s version 1.6.2.